# Sencha Touch add view inside viewport, position it absolute, on top of all other views of the app

Tags: sencha-touch-2

In Sencha Touch, I have created a view which contains some legal text.

How can I add that view inside the **ViewPort**, make it position absolute and make it sit on top of all other views from the Viewport?

The view is basically a legal disclaimer, with a transparent background, which needs to always be visible in the viewport, on top of all other views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your requirements, you can do that by using a simple `Ext.Container` with `centered: true`.

See an example here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/5s9